# How can I create an array with all rows from database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi is there any way I could loop throw my rows in DB and if the value Popular is = 1 assign its id to an array? Basically I need to cycle thru my products table and assign all id of rows that product is = 1 to an array so I can use it later in my HTML.
I'm using PHP7

Here is what I tried to achieve this:

```
//Variables
  $Host = 'localhost';
  $UserName = 'root';
  $Password = 'NOP';
  $DataBaseName = 'BoosTemplatesDB';
  $DEBUG = True;

  $link = mysqli_connect($Host, $UserName, $Password, $DataBaseName);

  // If the script cant connect to DB it will redirect to 409 error page and exit.
  if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    if ($DEBUG == True) {
      die ('MySQL error trying to connect to host '.mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
      header("Location: http://127.0.0.1/409.html");
      exit();
    }
  }

  $query_products = 'SELECT * FROM Products';
  $result = $link->query($query_products);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    $Popular = array();

    while($row != 4) {
        if ($row['Popular'] == 1) {
          $value = $row['ID'];
          array_push($Popular,$value);
        }
    }
    echo $value;
  } else {
    if ($DEBUG == True) {
      die ('MySQL couldnt find any result for the query: '.$query_products);
    } else {
      header("Location: http://127.0.0.1/409.html");
      exit();
    }
  }

$link->close();
```

My DB:
[image]

Comment: You completely neglected to actually _fetch_ any records from the result set here, but you are trying to read from a variable $row that was not defined or assigned a value anywhere.

Comment: (And if you are _only_ interested in products that have Popular = 1, you should select only those products from the database to begin with, by using an appropriate WHERE clause.)

Comment: Change your query to ```SELECT * FROM `Products` WHERE `Popular`=1``` to get only the products you want to filter by Popular = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking the value of `Popular` on PHP side, you can filter directly your rows like this, and return the list of ID directly

```
SELECT ID FROM Products WHERE Popular = 1;
```

Then, you can use [`mysqli_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) to get the results as an array directly

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $Popular[] = $row;
}

print_r($Popular)
```

Comment: I did this `  $query_products = 'SELECT ID FROM Products WHERE Popular = 1;';
  $result = $link->query($query_products);

  $Popular = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  print_r($Popular);` but its only printing the row with id 3 when it should print the id 5 and 6

Comment: My bad. You need to wrap the `mysqli_fetch_array` in a while loop as you must call it on each and every rows in the result set. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Im using this mysqli syntax, i think its simpler than the one youre using

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($Host, $UserName, $Password, $DataBaseName);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connexion error : %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$query = 'SELECT  * FROM Products';
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
     if(row['Popular']==1) { 
          //do your thing with row['ID'] 
     }
}
```

Also, why do you not simply make the request "SELECT ID from products where Popular = 1" ?