# My php isnt working as it should and i can find the problem

Tags: php, mysql

I want it to get the values from my DB and echo to the webpage but it's echoing no results found.

**MY code:**

```
//Variables
$Host = 'localhost';
$UserName = 'root';
$Password = 'NOP';
$DataBaseName = 'BoosTemplatesDB';
$DEBUG = True;

$link = mysqli_connect($Host, $UserName, $Password, $DataBaseName);
$query_items = 'SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ID = 6';
$result      = $link->query($query_items);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // Fetch one and one row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row[1];
    }
} else {
    echo 'No result found';
}
```

**MY DB:**
[image]

Comment: What is `$link`? What is `var_dump($result);`

Comment: `The behaviour of mysqli_num_rows() depends on whether buffered or unbuffered result sets are being used. For unbuffered result sets, mysqli_num_rows() will not return the correct number of rows until all the rows in the result have been retrieved.`

Comment: @Qirel My bad just updated the post

Comment: What is `var_dump($result);` and are you certain the connection is established? You do *no* form of error-checking here

Comment: *"My php isnt working as it should and i can find the problem"* Knowing how to debug in PHP is important and or which functions/methodes/approaches can/should be used `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`  ...  `if(!is_resource($link)) { echo mysqli_error($link); }` ... `if(!$result) { echo mysqli_error($link); }`

Comment: @AlaaMorad both queries mean the same thing in this case as Products isn't a reserved word your rewite does not change a thing.. i would suggest you to research what backticks really mean/do in MySQL..

Comment: @RaymondNijland You are right .. I have to delete my comment

Comment: I agree with @Qirel, If the root account is being used, chances are there might not be a password since the database is being hosted locally.

Comment: @ARubiksCube I seated up a password for root!

Comment: @Qirel I know that the conection is astablished because i have an if condition to check for error! Thats only the part i need help from my code!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create an array with all rows from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768553/how-can-i-create-an-array-with-all-rows-from-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mix between procedural style and object oriented style.

on `$link->query($query_items);` you are using the object oriented class.
here `mysqli_num_rows($result)` you are verifying it using the procedural style.

try to use

```
$link = mysqli_connect($Host, $UserName, $Password, $DataBaseName);
$query_items = 'SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ID = 6';
$result      = $link->query($query_items);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Fetch one and one row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row[1];
    }
} else {
    echo 'No result found';
    echo $link->error; // show last error.
}
```

edit: added $link->error; to see the last error for debugging purposes.

Hope it helps.

As Qirel stated you can mix procedural and object oriented from the documentation [PHP Manual Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php)

Mixing styles

It is possible to switch between styles at any time. Mixing both styles is not recommended for code clarity and coding style reasons.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. You can mix procedural MySQLi with object oriented MySQLi - it's not recommended (just to be consistent), but that will work just the same.

Comment: I did it like that but its steel saying no results found but it isn't printing echo $link->error; // show last error.! In case your asking the DB is connected because it would give an error.

Comment: And what was the problem, @DeadSec? This answer hardly seems to answer anything.

Comment: I think there was something ending the connection so I repeated the connection before the code and it worked